# Can't see fragment in fragment placeholder

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to show a fragment in the main activity where i have placed a "fragment placeholder"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_music) {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.text);
        t.setText(R.string.Musikken);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new MusicFragment());
        ft.commit();
    } else if
```

What am I douing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the framelayout is hiding behind the relative layout. Problem solved. I just had to remove android:layout_weight="1"